# How do I create dynamic definitions for state machine based on user defined data in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, state-machine-workflow

I am trying to write an application that will allow users to manage workflows using the [State Machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) but I am not sure how to proceed in allowing users to define their own state machines using the State Machine gem for ruby.

In the [dynamic definitions](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#static--dynamic-definitions) portion of the gem documentation it says that I should be able to do this by replacing code like this below with a data source.

```
   def transitions
    [
      {:parked => :idling, :on => :ignite},
      {:idling => :first_gear, :first_gear => :second_gear, :on => :shift_up}
      # ...
    ]
  end
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this. how do I define the transistions from a database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `transitions` is just a method, you could implement this any way you want. Here's one possible way.

I'll assume you're using ActiveRecord.

Define a Transition model and an associated transitions table with to, from, and on columns, all strings. Then you can start defining transitions, e.g.:

```
Transition.create(:from => "parked", :to => "idling", :on => "ignite")
```

Then in your transitions method:

```
def transitions
  transitions_data = []
  Transition.all.each do |transition|
    transitions_data << { transition.from.to_sym => transition.to.to_sym, :on => transition.on.to_sym }  
  end
  transitions_data
end
```

You can then use the other code in the documentation you linked to create a state machine dynamically.

This is just one example, and could be much further optimized. I'll leave that part to you. Hopefully this will give you a good start.